# Weird User-defined Comparison struct Error for priority_queue in C++

Tags: c++, templates, comparison

This is weird that the following code fails compilation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    char  data;
    Node* next;
    Node(char c, struct Node* nptr = nullptr)
        : data(c), next(nptr) {}
};

struct NodeCmp {
    bool operator()(const Node*& lhs, const Node*& rhs) const {
        return lhs->data > rhs->data;
    }
};

int main() {
    priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, NodeCmp> PQ;

    return 0;
}
```

with error:

```
prog.cpp:13:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:123:46: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'const Node*&' from an rvalue of type 'const Node*'
         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
                                              ^
```

See this IDE one link: http://ideone.com/T2ST03

However, the following which uses template is fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    char  data;
    Node* next;
    Node(char c, struct Node* nptr = nullptr)
        : data(c), next(nptr) {}
};

template <class T>
struct NodeCmp {
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const {
        return lhs->data > rhs->data;
    }
};

int main() {
    priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, NodeCmp<Node*>> PQ;

    return 0;
}
```

See the IDE one link: http://ideone.com/xPcNFK

I want to understand how could this happen, and why it's like this in C++? Thanks.

Comment: Similar: if you have `typedef int* int_ptr;`, `const int_ptr` is not the same type as `const int*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const T&` with `T = Node*` is `Node* const&`, not `const Node*&`:

- `Node * const& p` is a *const reference* to a pointer to a *non-const `Node`*, i.e. you cannot modify it, but you can modify what it points to.
- `const Node*&` is a *non-const reference* to a pointer to a *const `Node`*, i.e. you can modify the pointer, but not what it points to.

If you know you are dealing with pointers, just don't use references:

```
bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const
```

Comment: Hmmm, it is almost a habit for me to write `const T& lhs, and const T& rhs`, and I didn't realize that `const T&` (with `T = Node*`) resolves to `Node* const&`

Answer (score 2):

This is a (non-const lvalue) reference to a pointer-to-`const Node`:

```
const Node*& lhs
```

A non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to temporaries in standard C++. This is the reason for the compiler error. The simplest fix is to not pass references at all:

```
bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const
```

The reason it works with the template example is that, for `T = Node*`, `const T&` resolves to `const` reference to `Node*`.